# How can i get the typed in data as string and submit in my `MDEditor` of react app

Tags: reactjs, react-markdown, react-md-editor

How can I submit all of the typed data in `MDEditor` in my react app ? I have tried the below way to submit, but i am not getting the whole types in data as string, could someone please advise me ?

```
import MDEditor from '@uiw/react-md-editor';

const [value, setValue] = React.useState("**Create a new blog**");

const handleChange = (value) => {
  // Updating the state here... 
  setValue(value);
  
  const fetchData = async (value) => {
      try{
       
       const res = await axios.post(`${appURL}/service/createBlog`, {value });

        if (res.data.success) {
          // do rest of the 
        }
        else {
          
        }
       } catch (e){
            console.log(e);
           
        }
     }
     fetchData();
  
}

<div className='container'>
    <MDEditor
       className='reactEditorArea'
       value={value}
       onChange={handleChange}
    />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fetchData` has property `value` but you call it without `value`, `fetchData()`.

To-BE

```
const handleChange = (value) => {
  // ...
   fetchData(value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you while sending along with POST req, should send ait any specfic format ?